# How can I create a RAM disk and install Firefox into it?

Tags: firefox, memory, performance, fedora, sublime-text-2

I've a Fedora 22 64-bits system running under a notebook with Intel Core i3 processor and 7.7GB of RAM. I only use about 2~3GB of RAM (with everything I need) and I want to speed up my system, so I've searched and I found some informations about RAM disk.

A friend of mine tell me that I can install Firefox, Sublime Text and other small programs on my RAM disk, so I can start it directly from the RAM (what will make them run much faster). I have read some answers here on StackOverflow but it didn't helped me at all. I've a bunch of questions, can you help me?

### My questions are:

1. Can I install Firefox, Sublime Text or other small programs on my RAM disk to speed them up?
2. Should I do that? If so, how I can achieve this?

**P.S:** I'm coursing Science Computer, so I'm very open to know new things about Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider breaking up your question into separate questions - although they are related some of your questions will attract opinionated answers.

Comment: I also should have said there is a [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)  site in stackexchange - if you are really interested in the guts of GNU/Linux then there is [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/)